# Dexie Live Query and Service Worker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, reactive, dexie

I want to use Dexie within the service worker to sync my data.
I also want to use useLiveQuery hook in the React frontend.

Would Dexie automatically update the query if new data gets written in the service worker thread?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If data is written to the database by your Service worker, the React frontend will be notified instantly and update accordingly. Communication goes via BroadcastChannel. If using a legacy Safari browser that lacks BroadcastChannel support, dexie has a fallback so that mutations done in the service worker will be communicated using postMessage(). This is all taken care of by dexie itself.